# Removing the union from a query and converted it into one query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been told to remove the union and change the top half of the query into one, I have been told this is easy but I cannot figure it out. I have been told that it will include something like

Where Red (Major Colour) = Red (SilksName) 
Where Blue (Major Colour) = Blue (SilksName) 
etc

```
Select S.[Silks_Skey]
    from [dbo].[Silks] S 
    inner join [dbo].[SubColour] SC on CHARINDEX(SC.[SubColour],S.[SilksName]) <> 0
    inner join [dbo].[MajorColour] MC on SC.[MajorColour] = MC.[MajorColour]

    UNION ALL

    Select S.[Silks_Skey], MC.[MajorColour_Skey] 
    from [dbo].[Silks] S 
    inner join [dbo].[MajorColour] MC on CHARINDEX(MC.[MajorColour],S.[SilksName]) <> 0

    ORDER BY S.[Silks_Skey]
```

Comment: This sounds like something you should be asking **specifically** whoever told you "to remove the union" and that "this is easy" and that "it will include something like `...`"

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why you should remove `UNION ALL` from the query, it is the best option, although you could move the UNION to a subquery:

```
SELECT  S.[Silks_Skey], c.[MajorColour_Skey] 
FROM    [dbo].[Silks] S 
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  [Colour] = sc.[SubColour], mc.[MajorColour_Skey]
            FROM    [dbo].[SubColour] sc
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[MajorColour] mc 
                        ON sc.[MajorColour] = mc.[MajorColour]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  mc.[MajorColour], mc.[MajorColour_Skey]
            FROM    [dbo].[MajorColour] mc 
        ) c
            ON CHARINDEX(c.[Colour], S.[SilksName]) <> 0
```

If you **HAVE** to remove `UNION` you could use this:

```
SELECT  S.[Silks_Skey], mc.[MajorColour_Skey] 
FROM    [dbo].[Silks] S
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].[SubColour] sc
            ON CHARINDEX(sc.[SubColour], S.[SilksName]) <> 0
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[MajorColour] mc
            ON CASE WHEN sc.SubColour IS NOT NULL AND mc.MajourColour = sc.MajourColour THEN 1
                    ELSE CHARINDEX(mc.[MajorColour], S.[SilksName]) <> 0 
                END <> 0
```

But I cannot envisage this performing better than the UNION.

Note I hve just seen your answer and I would opt for the `CASE` in the join rather than `OR`, the case statement will shortcircuit so when a subcolour exists it does not evaluate the second part, whereas the OR will evaluate both.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks

```
Select S.[Silks_Skey], MC.[MajorColour_Skey]
from [dbo].[Silks] S 
left join [dbo].[SubColour] SC on CHARINDEX(SC.[SubColour],S.[SilksName]) <> 0
inner join [dbo].[MajorColour] MC on SC.[MajorColour] = MC.[MajorColour]
or CHARINDEX(MC.[MajorColour],S.[SilksName]) <> 0
```